# Is there any way to record mouse left button holds and then make mouse holds its left button?

Tags: c++, winapi

Im writing a c++ code that open paint,then record mouse movements (actually the draw in paint) in an array and then  open another paint and force mouse to move in its last movements which i have stored,here i need to force mouse to draw same thing that i draw in previous paint.i need a function that holds mouse left button while i force it to move.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include<winuser.h>

int main()
{
    POINT Mouse;
    POINT mousePositions[20];
    int counter = 0;
    ShellExecute(NULL, TEXT("open"), TEXT("F://paint"), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
    while (counter<20)
    {
        GetCursorPos(&Mouse);
        mousePositions[counter] = Mouse;
        counter++;
        Sleep(500);
    }
    counter = 0;
    ShellExecute(NULL, TEXT("open"), TEXT("F://paint"), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
    while (counter<20)
    {

        SetCursorPos(mousePositions[counter].x, mousePositions[counter].y);
        counter++;
        Sleep(500);
    }

    getche();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You would need to listen events of paint window process, by [SetWinEventHook function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook)

Comment: Why do you use double-forward-slashes?

Comment: This seems like a mix of C++ and C (`conio.h` belongs to C library,`return 0` is needless in C++). You should clarify what language you want to use.

Comment: The above program would be very imprecise… Mouse can move a lot in 500ms.

Comment: You can simulate mouse events with `SendInput`

Comment: `SetWindowsHookEx()` with `WH_JOURNALRECORD` and `WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK` is designed for this kind of scenario. Recording input events and then playing them back

Comment: @RemyLebeau Can you help me with this code, i studied setWindowsHookEx() but i didnt understand it,how can i make my code repeat its actions using these functions?